# PHP MySQL Two Queries - Foreach

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I have two tables, one contains all the available working hours in a day, and the other table contains the hours someone states they are available. When I create my `<select>` form field I want to auto select which time is already in the DB for that `tutor_id` in `tutor_ availability` for that day and time.

```
      hours_list                                tutor_availability
----------------------               --------------------------------------       
  24hour   |   12hour                tutor_id | day | start_time | end_time
----------------------               --------------------------------------
  1000     |   10:00am                 27     | mon |   1000     |   1100
----------------------               --------------------------------------
  1030     |   10:30am
----------------------
  1100     |   11:00am
----------------------
  1130     |   11:30am
----------------------
//the list goes on
```

I have tried several queries with `Left Join`'s with little success. I was thinking I could do two seperate queries but then I am running into a problem with how to select the right option field while iterating over the results from `hours_list`:

```
$hours = Select * FROM hours_list;
//next query
$available = Select day, start_time, end_time 
FROM tutor_availability WHERE tutorid = '27';

foreach ($hours as $option) { 
echo '<option value="' . $option['24hour'] . '"';
if ($available['start_time'] == $option['24hours'] && $available['day'] == 'mon') {   
echo 'selected'; }
//rest here
```

However, I can't figure out how to iterate over the two sql results in conjunction to get the right results.

Comment: what is the relation between first table and second?

Comment: @PrasanthBendra There really is no relation. The first table stores all the hours (ie: 24 hours in a day). The second table stores the availability that the tutors select. The first table is static, only stored in MySQL for each of use for iterating over the hours to make the select options.

Answer (score 0):

```
$hours  = array();
$avail  = array();
$query  = mysql_query("Select * FROM hours_list");

while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
   $hours[]   = $result['24hour'] 
}

$available = mysql_query("Select day, start_time, end_time 
FROM tutor_availability WHERE tutorid = '27'");

while($res  = mysql_fetch_assoc($available)){
    $avail[] = $res['start_time'];
}


foreach($hours as $hour){
echo '<option value="' . $hour . '"';
if (in_array($hour, $avail)) {   
echo 'selected >'.$hour.' </option>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think no need to fire JOIN query, if you are using database only upto this much small scope. **But always use mysqli_* functions as mysql_* are deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0.** (Refer [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) ) 
Below is the desired code.

```
    //Connect to db
    $link =mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");

    // Get all hours record as all are needed in dropdown
    $hours = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM hours_list");

    // Get desired tutor record as it is to be shown as selected
    $tut=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM tutor_availability WHERE tut_id=27");
    $tut1= mysqli_fetch_assoc($tut);

    //echo dropdown script
    echo "<select name='testSelect'>";
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($hours)){

        echo '<option value="' . $row['twentyFourHour']. '" ';
        if ($tut1['start_time'] == $row['twentyFourHour'] && $tut1['day'] == 'mon') {
            //show this option as selected.
            echo ' selected ';
        }
        echo ">".$row['twelveHour']."</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
```